# Raspbian Jessie - Transmission won't save to Windows share - Permission denied

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, permissions

I can't say how many hours I've spent trying to get this to work. I'm about ready to donate this new Raspberrry Pi 3 to a local school and pick up an Intel Compute Stick running Windows for my download machine!

Does anyone have Transmission successfully downloading to a Windows share on Jessie?

- Created local mount point "/media/windowsshare" in /etc/fstab with the following lie
- //192.168.0.6/d/downloads /media/windowsshare cifs username=*WINDOWS_USER_WITH_FULL_CONTROL*,password=*PASSWORD*,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0

I can read/write files to the shared windows folder without any issues in the File Explorer. However, Transmission gives me "permission denied" when trying to down a torrent. I've followed countless guides online and changed the account Transmission runs under, changed folder permissions, file permissions, among other things. Over the past few years, there are too many suggestions to get this working that do not seem to work on Jessie. What am I doing wrong? No one has access to this machine, and there is nothing on it, so I don't mind using root if that's easiest. *I know that is not recommended)

Comment: I don't have a suitable Pi handy to test this on. Someone [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=119217) had an identical problem which was resolved by 'Adding file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 to the mount line in fstab'. There are some fstab/drive mounting instructions [here](http://www.noveldevices.co.uk/rp-cifsinfstab).

Comment: @goobering That did the trick! Thanks! Why don't you make this an answer so you can get credit for it?

Comment: Late/tired/tiny tiny phone keyboard! Happy to have helped. I'd have no problem whatsoever if you'd like to write it up and grab a couple of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the permissions at mount time in fstab like below. After restarting the machine, downloads started working fine with all other configs and permissions set to the default in the Transmission configs.

```
 //192.168.0.6/d/downloads /media/windowsshare cifs username=WINDOWS_USER_WITH_FULL_CONTROL,password=PASSWORD,uid=1000,gid=1000,**file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777**,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```